# Tkinter, элемент Text

Tags: python, tkinter

Пользователь вводит данные в элемент `Text`. Есть переменная (берётся из `Entry`) которая обозначает номер строки в `Text`, есть кнопка с функцией которая должна вывести текст написанный в указанной строке с помощью `print`. Пробовал экспериментировать со значениями `get`, но бессмысленно, не работает как хотелось бы. Жду помощи.

Comment: Покажите код, которому требуется помощь

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from tkinter import*
root = Tk()
txt = Text(root)
txt.pack()
def read_by_lines():
    text = txt.get('1.0', END).splitlines()
    for line in text:
        #do your stuff here
        pass
root.mainloop()
```